# Menu items with Userpoints total

Tags: routes, userpoints

Is it possible to show the current total userpoints a user have next to menu item?

example menu: Home | Downloads | **My Points (24)** | Logout

if it's possible, how would one do this (beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will return you user points :

```
<?php
print userpoints_get_current_points($user->uid);
?>
```

But to Place this PHP snippet in menu link, you may need [Menu views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views) and [PHP Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmenu) Modules

Comment: Thank you, it turns out you only need the Menu Views modules only to show the total amount of Userpoints as it already integrated inside views. Can't seem to upvote your anwers right now, I dont seem to have enough reputation. Will upvote it later :)

Comment: Glad that helped you :)